# solving equations by the method of elimination

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}=\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{3} \;\;\; \ldots(i)$$
$$x+1=y \;\; \;\ldots(ii)$$

We have to solve for $x$ and $y$, only this time using the method of elimination.

From equation $(ii)$, we get,
$$\frac{1}{x+1}=\frac{1}{y} \Rightarrow \frac{b}{x+1}=\frac{b}{y} \;\;\; \ldots(iii)$$

Subtracting $(iii)$ from $(i)$, we get,
$$\frac{a}{x}+\frac{b}{y}-\frac{b}{y}=\frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{3}- \frac{b}{x+1}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{a}{x}=\frac{a}{2}  + \frac{b}{3} -  \frac{b}{x+1}$$

After that,I really cannot find anything to do.I have taken quite a few other routes, but have hit nothing but dead ends. At this a point a little hint will be appreciated.

Comment: (iii) should be b/(x+1)=b/y

Comment: Why not just replace $y$ in (i) by $x+1$, solve for $x$, etc.?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson,because the book says to find it using the method of elimination.What is more,I already posted such a question a while back under the same title,except it was on the method of substitution.

Comment: @Sami Ben,fixed,ty.

Comment: And how am I supposed to know what you might have posted earlier, especially seeing how you chose not to include a link to it? Anyway, what do you mean by "elimination"? Haven't I eliminated $y$ from (i) by using (ii)?

Comment: @rahul, are you sure your final equation is correct? Please check your equations again.

Comment: Isn't it $\frac{b}{x+1}$?

Comment: @jaseem,Yes,I made a typo

Comment: @rahul, now multiply throughout by $6x(x+1)$, what do you get?

Comment: @TenaliRaman I seem to get something too big to solve,or am I just making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You've already done the "elimination" when you subtract (iii) from (i), and it looks like you have a typo, $y$ should be completely eliminated when you do the subtraction, and you should get

$$a/x = a/2 + b/3 - b/(x+1)$$

If you then multiply this equation by $x(x+1)$ on both sides (keeping in mind then that $x$ cannot be $0$ or $-1$), and cancel the $x$ and $(x+1)$ in denominators, and then expand and bring all terms to one side then you will get a quadratic in $x$ that is set to $0$, which you can solve for $x$.  Then you can substitute into (ii) to easily get $y$.

Note that when you solve the quadratic, you are assuming either $a \neq 0$ or $b \neq 0$.  If $a = b = 0$ then any $x$ gives a solution except $x = 0
$ and $x = -1$.

Comment: But doesn't multiplying by x(x+1) cancel only two denominators?

Comment: Pure numerical denominators like $2$ and $3$ don't need to be cancelled, but if you want you can multiply by $6x(x+1)$ and that will cancel all denominators

Comment: Okay. That gives us ax +a=(3ax^2+3ax+2bx^2-4bx)/6.Now how do we solve the quadratic?